# AVCaptureSession audio samples captured at different frequency than AVAudioSession's sample rate

Tags: audio, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

I'm using AVFoundation capture session to output audio buffers through AVCaptureAudioDataOutput. The capture session is using the default application audio session. (ie. captureSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = true). I don't alter the audio session in any way.

The strange behavior is that the capture session returns audio buffers captured at a different frequency than the default audio session's sample rate.

Specifically:

```
print(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate) \\ 48000
```

but

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if connection.audioChannels.first != nil {
            print(sampleBuffer.presentationTimeStamp) \\ CMTime(value: 2199812320, timescale: 44100, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 3), epoch: 0)
            delegate?.captureOutput(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, mediaType: .audio)
        } 
    }
```

My expected behavior is that the sample buffer's timescale would also be 48000.

For a little extra info, if I do change the default audio session, for example, change preferred sample rate to 48000, the sample buffer's timescale will change to 48000 as expected. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the capture session's `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` to false and do your own audio session configuration before starting the capture session.

Like this:

```
// use audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate() to request desired sample rate
captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord) // or just record
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) // worked without this, but feels wrong
```