# How to change the sample rate of a real device in ios

Tags: ios

I'm developing a simple recording app using `AVAudioSession`, `AVAudioRecorder`. And I'm having trouble changing the sample rate of a ios real device.

An attempt was made to change the sample rate using the `setPreferredSampleRate` function, and this attempt was well applied in all simulators. In this case, I checked that the sample rate has changed by checking the `sampleRate` property of `AVAudioSession`.

However, it didn't work on a real device.
As a result of checking the `sampleRate` property, only the value of 48000 was found in the real device. The devices I tested were iphone 8 and iphone 8+.

I googled and read a lot of stackoverflow articles, but it was hard to find an article that could be applied to my problem.

Then I found an [article](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/22197), I read that "The internal speaker on the iPhone 6S models only support a sample rate of 48kHz."

I wonder if there is no way to change the sample rate in a real device as long as the internal speaker is used.

If there is a way, I don't think it's just to use `setPreferredSampleRate`... I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to do it.

Below is the class I wrote to manage AVAudioSession. I changed the sample rate and checked the value using the method below.

```
class AudioSessionManager{

private let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

func setAudioSession() {
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        audioSession.requestRecordPermission{ accepted in
            if accepted {
                print("permission granted")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func setSampleRate(_ sampleRate : Double) {
    do {
        try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(sampleRate)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func getSampleRate() -> Double {
    return audioSession.sampleRate
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly need to set `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` for the session to false before your settings are applied so that they are not overridden by the system.

Related question and answer: [AVCaptureSession audio samples captured at different frequency than AVAudioSession's sample rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666010/avcapturesession-audio-samples-captured-at-different-frequency-than-avaudiosessi)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the article you linked, but it doesn't seem to work because AVCaptureSession is not being used in my app. Just in case, I put ```AVCaptureSession().automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false``` before setting the sample rate, but nothing changed.